# Confusion on an example of Shafarevich regarding Ramification

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In section 2.6.3 (Ramification) of Shafarevich he makes an example to motivate the fact that for a finite morphism $f:X\to Y$ in which $X,Y$ are irreducible and $\dim X=\dim Y$ we expect the fibers to have a constant cardinality over almost all of $Y$ (That is on a non-empty open set). But his example is confusing to me. The example is:

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1$ given by $y=f(x) =x^2$ then clearly except for $y=0$, $|f^{-1}(y)|=2$. That is fine and all if it is used for some intuition but this not a finite morphism! If it was finite it would be closed but $f(\mathbb{A}^1)$ is nowhere near closed in $\mathbb{A}^1$. It has finite fibers but it is not a finite morphism.

So do I have a misunderstanding or is it really just a means for inspiration?

Comment: Why do you think it is not closed?

Comment: Every closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is a finite set of points. The image of $f$ is the half line to infinity in $\mathbb{A}^1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Shafarevich works over an algebraically closed field $k$, not over $\mathbb R$. There are no half lines in $k$.

Comment: Oh, my... Thank you... Of course you're right... I'm brain dead apparently...

Comment: Not that it is important as  Georges Elencwajg  says. But, even over the reals, the map is closed, it is the closed half line.

Comment: I was thinking half in algebraic geometry (Zariski) and half real number intuition (hence the half line).

Comment: Note that $k[x]$ is, as a module, free of finite rank over $k[y]$ — one basis is $\{1,x\}$. Eisenbud has some cute examples at the start of _View_ showing how misleading the real picture can be.